# How do I connect to a remote mysql kubernetes pod using mysql client

Tags: mysql, kubernetes

I have a got a kubernetes mysql pod which is exposed as a nodePort like shown below

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: demo-mysql
  labels:
    app: demo
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 3306
      nodePort: 32695
```

I am trying to access this mysql server using the command below

```
mysql -u root -h 117.213.118.86 -p 32695
```

but I get this error

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '117.213.118.86' (111)
```

What am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
mysql -u root --password=<PASSWORD> -h <CLUSTER_HOST> --port=32695
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to connect to a remote mysql service, you have to specify an endpoint that has the remote service's ip addrress like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  name: demo-mysql
subsets:
  - addresses:
      - ip: 192.0.2.42
    ports:
      - port: 3306
```

More details [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#services-without-selectors).